# Facebook graph API Insights requests limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-insights

I have an app which manages hundreds of Facebook pages. Now I need to make a dashboard which will show reports based on Facebook insights for every page but when I try to get the data from Facebook I am getting a message saying that I am reaching the requests limit and I am not able to make requests to Facebook Insights any more.

For every page I get 10-15 metrics in a single request, but I have hundreds of pages.

I found that the limit is 200 App request per hour, but for insights there are different rules.

How I can make my dashboard works because even batch requests did not help?

Comment: Doesn't Facebook have any paid tiers? It looks as though you may fit in them.

Comment: are you using a page token or app token?

Comment: facebook does not have any paid tiers btw.

Comment: I am using page tokens because I can not get the desire metrics with the app token

Comment: ok, then i don´t know, i am afraid. btw, batch requests don´t count as one api call, they are just faster.

Comment: It's 200 calls per user per hour. Does all the pages belong to one user? If not, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Limiting for page tokens has recently been reworked, see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/06/16/page-level-rate-limits/

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the information. When facebook release this new limitation rules, my issue will be resolved. But till then I need to find another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Request that your app be upgraded to Standard Access. An overview of the access tiers and instructions for requesting an upgrade are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access